# apache2 virtualhost configuration

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I would like to configure Apache2 with multiple Virtualhosts.

It seems similar to : [Apache2 weird redirection. (Default site overriding others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153227/apache2-weird-redirection-default-site-overriding-others) but that question has no answer.

I used :

```
apache2cts -S
```

to check the status of the configuration, with result :

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server vbox4.dev.local (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost vbox4.dev.local (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)       
         port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.example.com.conf:4)
                 alias example.com
```

So it appears that Apache knows about the existence of the virtualhost, but if I enter www.example.com enter in the browser, after apache reload, still the default apache page is displayed.

[apache2 virtualhost configuration with two subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408755/apache2-virtualhost-configuration-with-two-subdirectories) come close but does not help me. 
[Configuring virtual hosts on apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484676/configuring-virtual-hosts-on-apache2) seemed to me very similar, but it does not give me sufficient information to solve my problem.

I followed already some suggestions, but when implementing I found this does not work (any more) Which I have read by other suggestions. I will not repeat these here to be brief.

My system :

- Run within a Virtualbox client
- using Ubuntu 14.04 as client OS

Steps I took:

- Follow the original instructions from http://www.debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2
- Result : In the browser localhost displays the "Apache2 Ubuntu default page"
  ** So apache2 itself seems to run ok.
- I followed all steps in the documentation for "www.example.com"
- I added in /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs a very small index.html file to identify this site

And reloaded apache

- Result : browser points to default localhost "Apache2 Ubuntu default page"
  but not to my expected small index.html file for this domain.

The /var/log/apache2/error.log shows no error.

Where did I made a mistake, and how tot solve?

Answer (score 0):

What actually you want to be done ? Two or more virtual hosts on the same server ? If so create 2 or so directories on your root folder e.g

```
mkdir /var/www/html/example.com
mkdir /var/www/html/anotherhost.com
```

Now create test pages for both the hosts to differentiate them. Now create two separate virtual host files, first copy the default config file into the domain.conf:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/anotherhost.com.conf
```

Open your new config file into an editor, I use nano

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
```

Make the content look like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Do the same for another host and enable the virtual hosts

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
sudo a2ensite anotherhost.com.conf
```

restart apache

Comment: I did so.The main difference with your suggestion is the path of the Virtualhost in /var/www/html/example.com instead of my /var/www/example.com , so without html. But without result. Any other suggestions?